# What exactly does the strip() command do? Example from: Beautiful Soup and webscraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, strip

I have the following code, and have extracted the text only, getting rid of the tags, using .text. Tutorials and documentation suggest using .strip as well, but I cannot see the difference. What does strip() actually do in this case?

```
url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
req = requests.get(url)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")

data=bsObj.find_all('div',class_="maincounter-number")

print(data)
print()
totalcases=data[0].text
print(totalcases)
totalcases_stripped=totalcases.strip()
print()
print()
print("Stripped total cases:",totalcases_stripped)
```

As far as I can see: print("Stripped total cases:",totalcases_stripped) produces the same output as the first total cases without the strip applied.

**Output:**

```
Powered by 
[<div class="maincounter-number">
<span style="color:#aaa">11,227,486 </span>
</div>, <div class="maincounter-number">
<span>529,837</span>
</div>, <div class="maincounter-number" style="color:#8ACA2B ">
<span>6,369,639</span>
</div>]


11,227,486 



Stripped total cases: 11,227,486
```

I'd appreciate a clear answer with examples if possible explaining the use and application of strip.

Comment: Your question asks for the purpose of the split command while your question body is asking for the strip command. I suggest you fix this.

Comment: you don't use there 'split()' you are using `strip()`

Comment: the strip just delete empty spaces on start and end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip removes the starting and ending extra spaces in the text.
There is `rstrip & lstrip` too which removes the spaces on the defined side

Strip is not part of Beautifulsoup and in the title you have mentioned as `split`, but description has `strip`

Comment: @MissComputing - If you find the answer useful & correct. Please mark it as answer

Answer (score 1):

this `strip()` attribute removes the spaces before the particular word and after it for example

```
txt = '     example     '
print(txt.strip())
# output 
# 'example'
```

the whitespaces before the word and after it it washed away